# Is this possible regarding diagram of vectors?

Tags: vectors

Vector A is joined head to tail with vector B.Then I join vector C tail to head of vector A but it automatically  gets joined tail to tail with vector B.
Can this representation of vectors be right or wrong and what is the correct way to solve it then ?[image]

Comment: Interesting that you use the word "solve" - what is it that you're solving? And indeed, I do not see any problems with the picture. Notice that vectors, in their purest meaning, don't store information about **where** they are. So they can be moved around as much as you like, and therefore this kind of picture looks good to me.

Comment: Ok thanks ... .

Comment: I will use this then.